# VirtualBox shared folder is accessible but not workable

Tags: virtualbox, permissions, shared-folders

On my host system (Windows 8 Pro 64 Bit), I installed VirtualBox (4.2.12) and installed Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit as guest system. I also installed the VirtualBox guest utilities to create shared folders.

Now, after creating a shared folder, I added my user id to the group `vboxsf`, which is the owner of the shared folder with

`sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf <my-user-id>`

After a re-login to the Ubuntu system, I can access the shared folder and create a text file in it. But when using a text editor like gedit or Geany, I encounter a strange problem. When I try to save the file, the original file will be removed from the disk and gedit tells me

`Could not save the file /media/sf_shared_folder/test.txt` and

`Unexpected error: Error renaming temporary file: Text file busy`

Why there are conflicts when I am already in the group? And how to solve them?

[image]

Comment: Workaround: does it work with `mount -t vboxsf uid=1000,gid=1000 <folder-name> <mount-point>`, possibly without you being in the vboxsf group?

Comment: You should reboot your Ubuntu after you changed a user's group membership.

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the same issue. My setup: VirtualBox 4.2.12 with Ubuntu 13.04 guest running on W7SP1 host, mounted Windows folder with fstab like this

```
dev /home/dregad/dev    vboxsf  auto,rw,uid=dregad,gid=dregad,umask=0022,dmode=0755,fmode=0644  0   0
```

I'm using Geany. Saving the file fails with similar symptoms as described in the question above for gedit (which fails too). Error message as follows:

```
Error saving file.
Error renaming temporary file: Text file busy
The file on disk may now be truncated!
```

My solution for Geany:

- Edit / Preferences
- Select *Various* tab
- scroll down and check the box for **[use_atomic_file_saving](http://wiki.geany.org/config/all_you_never_wanted_to_know_about_file_saving#use_atomic_file_saving)**
- click OK

I don't use it much, so not sure if gedit provides a similar trick, but FWIW, you may want to have a look at [this stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52951/gedit-wont-save-a-file-on-a-virtualbox-share-text-file-busy) as it offers a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is fundamentally with glib and the way it saves to a temporary file, then renames without closing the file. The bug has been recorded as:  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656225

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you edit the file using the Texteditor (Gedit) which is default text editor we have with ubuntu.

I have used the **Sublime text editor** and **error won't happen**. **No need of additional headaches of manual or auto mount changes.**

Please refer : https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2553 for more detail.

It saved lot of time of mine !!!